# the same asp.net web application with different look

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I recently created a simple asp.net webapplication and hosted in a server in my company. I need the same application for several clients, and I have to change just labels and images according to the client. Something like: "www.mycompany.com/mywebapp/client1", "www.mycompany.com/mywebapp/client2", "www.mycompany.com/mywebapp/client3"

But logic and database is the same. How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: well you would need a database table with all clients listed and other table with the clientID as Foreign Key and custom values as needed. how does it sound? in fact in many cases depending on data volumes and traffic you would opt for a separated database per each client so that you can distribute the load on different db servers and backup/restore/modify separately.

Comment: The easy and more direct way is to create different CSS file for each website, recreate your labels on server side

Answer (score 0):

If it's a .Net web application or a .Net website, you would use [MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) and user controls. This would allow you to have functionality restricted to the user controls and all style/layout considerations handled in the master pages.

If you choose to use MVC you would be using layout pages for a similar purpose and partial views in place of usercontrols.

In the case in the question, each subfolder would have its own master page:

```
mywebapp/client1/client1.master
mywebapp/client2/client2.master
mywebapp/client3/client3.master
```

and the pages inside would simply have the master page definitions and inclusion of the user controls. Your user controls would then sit in a public common folder such as:

```
mywebapp/sharedcontrols/login.ascx
mywebapp/sharedcontrols/clientinfodisplay.ascx
```

Comment: With master pages I think it will be hard to reuse same pages a cross clients.

Comment: @EmmanuelN: It's not. I do it all the time. As long as your controls are managed through styles and the styles are consistent, it's a snap.  It's fairly rare, but there are minor occasions where my usercontrols have to have specific code to change something minor, but this will be the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

We did this slightly differently.  In our case the DNS names are client1.mycompany.com

All of the DNS names are pointed at the exact same "web site" under IIS.  In our master page we detect the subdomain (ie: client1) and look up the internal client id for it.

Also, we have a "skins" directory which holds the custom css and images for the client.  For example /Skins/34/custom.css or /Skins/34/logo.png

Back in the master page we inject the appropriate CSS file which contains the overrides necessary to meet that customers look/feel.

For example, in our default css file we might have a definition like:

```
#customerLogo { background-image: url('/images/default.png');
```

then in the customer specific css file we'll have something like:

```
#customerLogo { background-image: url('/skins/34/logo.png') !important;
```

This allows our custom file to override the default css class definitions.  Further, it allows us to override just the particular elements that need it instead of having to have a full css file per client.